# Dump database and re-import under a new name

Tags: arangodb

If I need to duplicate the contents of a database "foo" into a second database "bar" with MySQL, I would usually do something like this:

```
mysqldump -u root foo > foo.sql
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE bar;"
mysql -u root bar < foo.sql
```

What would be the equivalent procedure with ArangoDB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [arangodump](https://docs.arangodb.com/Arangodump/README.html) and [arangorestore](https://docs.arangodb.com/Arangorestore/README.html) tools, for example:

```
arangodump --server.database myDatabase1 --output-directory "myDumpFolder"
arangorestore --server.database myDatabase2 --input-directory "myDumpFolder"
```