# How to duplicate database in ArangoDB when you can't run arangodump

Tags: database, arangodb

I want to make a clone/duplicate of a database I have in ArangoDB. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/27827457 is one way I saw to do it, but it doesn't work for me because I can't run arangodump or any of the other Arango commands (like arangosh, arangorestore, etc.).

Also, why can't I run arangodump? This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63074313 says to "Open terminal and use cd to go to the directory in which arangoimport.exe is stored", but I can't find arangoimport.exe anywhere.

I looked on the ArangoDB website already, but I couldn't find any info.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to `arangodump` and `arangorestore` on server, then easiest way to invoke them is via docker and access your server by adding `--server.endpoint` option, you'll need to map some volume/directory to container to preserve dumped data for restoring them in other container, something like this:

```sh
#dump data to /tmp/dump at your host
docker run -it --rm -v /tmp/dump:/dump arangodb/arangodb:3.7.6 arangodump --server.endpoint http+tcp://192.168.1.2:8529
#restore data from /tmp/dump at your host
docker run -it --rm -v /tmp/dump:/dump arangodb/arangodb:3.7.6 arangorestore --server.endpoint http+tcp://192.168.1.2:8529
```

documentation of all available options, including examples are [here for arangodump](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangodump.html) and [here for arangorestore](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangorestore.html)

other option is to write your own implementation of dump and restore utilizing [ArangoDB REST APIs](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/), but that's hefty and error prone task comparing to installing docker and then running provided dump and restore tools

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "access to arangodump and arangorestore on server"? Also, I am currently not using docker or an external server, so I'm not sure how I would do this. Is there a way for me to install the arangodump and arangorestore features onto my computer?

Comment: Assuming that you have Windows, then you can get client tools at https://www.arangodb.com/download-major/windows/

Comment: Thanks! I did download and install the client tools but still don't have arangodump and arangorestore for some reason...

Comment: as per https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/installation-windows.html, your installation should be under C:\Program Files\ArangoDB-3.x.x (if you didn't change it), executables should be in bin subfolder. if you don't see them under that location download from https://www.arangodb.com/download-major/windows/ zip package of whole server, unzip it and use executables from usr/bin subfolder

Comment: @Auraxius - if this answered your question, please mark this as your selected answer.  It really helps others find the right solution in the future.  Thanks!